# What is the difference between X-Received and Received in email-header?

Tags: network, email

Also how to calculate delay between sent and received?

Comment: You will be more likely to get an answer if you add more information to your question. Perhaps stating the problem you are trying to solve would be a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between X-Received and Received in email-header?

Received is a header defined in the [standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) while X-Received is a non-standard header added by some user-agents or mail transfer agent like the google mail SMTP server.

> Also how to calculate delay between sent and received?

Look at the time stamps in the Received and Date headers, but at least some of them can be spoofed (to give the answer at least some relation to security, i.e. the topic of this site). You'll often find the Date header spoofed in spam mails so that they get a better place in the inbox.